# PIG ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I'm running simple pig script,but its keep on throwing exceptions which saying ;
org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input path does not exist

Believe me path is absolutely correct (as per my understanding) , i tried with same data in Local file system as well as in MapReduce mode but no difference. [image: Exception logs and HDFS path list]

---

Comment: What are the contents of "/user/pmishr0/prashant/gold_offer_taxonomy/_temporary/"?

Comment: I'm experiencing something similar. I think this is something unrelated to the  HDFS file. In my case it's complaining about a hive partition I'm not even using. I have a really complex prig script, and what I experienced if I STORE some intermediate results and than load them and continue the exec like this I could move forward. Strange, but I think this should be some resource allocation issue, but this is just a hint. I'll give an update if I fugure it out.

Answer (score 1):

I got the resolution , Reason behind is , The relation name and the path/folder specified have the same name , in such cases it will only not iterate the sub folders or directories and produce such error :)

Comment: I also found the root cause of my issue, and I just want to clarify what you found is the same: In my case I tried to join to "tables" which are originated from the same load source, and separated by filter (on a given partition). Some of my colleague said this is a known issue in PIG, you could work-a-round it by specify 2 load statements and filter the 2 tables from the 2 separate load. I hope it was clear.